# Not able to import a value as date in pandas read_excel, only obtain the first 1970 day

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

I want to import an excel file into pandas.
It has a column with dates, but when I import it, its type is numpy float64.
I obtain the following dataframe (first row):

```
totales.iloc[0]
```

returns

```
Fecha              44767.0
Monto                207.5
Otros    De Souza 2 fletes
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

The dtype of the value:

```
type(totales.iloc[0]["Fecha"])
```

returns:

```
numpy.float64
```

I have tried a lot of alternatives for instance:

```
totales["Fecha"]= totales["Fecha"].astype(str).astype("datetime64")
totales.iloc[0]["Fecha"]
```

returns

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000044767
```

44767.0 is the non converted value as shown.
I have also tried:

```
totales['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(totales['Fecha'], unit="s")
totales.head(1)
```

that returns:

```
Fecha         1970-01-01 12:26:07
Monto                       207.5
Otros           De Souza 2 fletes
```

I again obtain a date that is not the right one.
I have also tried other proposals unsuccesfully.
I will appreciate any solution to this problem

Comment: Try: `pd.to_datetime(totales['Fecha'], unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')` -> 2022-07-25